# Exception in thread QueueManagerThread - scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, scikit-learn, joblib

When I set **n_jobs=-1** I get error and if I set n_jobs equal **big value** (n_jobs=100), but if set smaller value (e.g. n_jobs=32), it works fine. I've tried **reinstall** scikit-learn and joblib packages, but to no avail. Also, it (n_jobs=-1) works fine previously, but suddenly go wrong.

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifier

iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris_X = iris.data
iris_y = iris.target

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0, shuffle=True)
scoring = {'accuracy': 'accuracy'}

model_ridge = RidgeClassifier(random_state=0)
scores = cross_validate(estimator=model_ridge, 
                            X=iris_X,
                            y=iris_y,
                            scoring=scoring,
                            cv=skf.split(iris_X, iris_y),
                            n_jobs=-1)
```

> Exception in thread QueueManagerThread:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 615, in _queue_management_worker
>       ready = wait(readers + worker_sentinels)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 859, in wait
>       ready_handles = _exhaustive_wait(waithandle_to_obj.keys(), timeout)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 791, in _exhaustive_wait
>       res = _winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects(L, False, timeout)
>
> ValueError: need at most 63 handles, got a sequence of length 65

Comment: This problem origin from joblib/loky. I created the [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13354) on github.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're running a lot of cores there! Set n_jobs=60 and this should work. See more details here https://github.com/psf/black/issues/564

Comment: This may work, but it ins't solution of this problem, because I would like to utilize cpu power completely. With similar success, I could dont use parallel computation at all.

Comment: Check out dask!