# Maximum workers when multiprocessing in Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Why is my maximum number of workers in `Pool` set to 60? Shouldn’t it be even lower, considering I only got 8 core CPU with 16 threads? For some reason it accepts 60 and it runs fine, not using up even 30% of the CPU, despite competing for resources and switching context.

As soon as I set to something like `Pool(61)` or higher, I get an error like this:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 519, in _handle_workers
    cls._wait_for_updates(current_sentinels, change_notifier)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 499, in _wait_for_updates
    wait(sentinels, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 884, in wait
    ready_handles = _exhaustive_wait(waithandle_to_obj.keys(), timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 816, in _exhaustive_wait
    res = _winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects(L, False, timeout)
ValueError: need at most 63 handles, got a sequence of length 82
```

Apparently, this is a Windows limitation, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252807/multiprocessing-pool-pool-on-windows-cpu-limit-of-63). But why?

If going over CPU thread limit is possible, why won’t Windows allow me to go to 80 or 120, considering I have CPU cycles to spare? Would this limitation still apply, if I installed Linux on this machine? Is there some other way to circumvent this? Do people with Threadripper CPUs also run into same issue on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Windows specific limit, tied to the `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` limit of [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) ([the limit is 64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5131807/364696)); you can see in your traceback that the ultimate problem is the call to `_winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects`; that's Windows-specific code. On Linux you should have no such problems.

There are [ways around this limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5136775/364696) (it basically involves creating nested hierarchies of handles to wait on), but it's complicated and has limitations; clearly the Python level code hasn't bothered to make use of any of these workarounds. Within Python, I think you're stuck using multiple pools if you want to exceed the limit. Since the limit is on how many handles can be monitored in a single call to `WaitForMultipleObjects`, not a limit on total processes, multiple pools should work just fine.

Comment: my 2¢... If you need that many processes, probably better to construct your own "Pool" from `mp.Process`, and other constructs. You can sometimes do slightly better in terms of overhead by customizing to your specific application rather than the built-in Pool. (mostly by optimizing what you send and how you send data to the child processes)

Comment: @Aaron: Yeah. It's a fairly significant undertaking to rewrite a custom `Pool`, but if you honestly need hundreds of processes, it's an option.